# Slicer: continue exploring path after reading indeterminate value

Tags: c, frama-c

I would like to slice the following program:

```
int main() {
  int j;
  if (j) {
ERROR:
    /*@ slice pragma ctrl; */
    goto ERROR;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Currently, Frama-C stops exploring the path after the read of `j`, resulting in the `ERROR` label sliced away:

```
$ frama-c test.c -slice-pragma main -then-on 'Slicing export' -print
[...]
test.c:3:[kernel] warning: accessing uninitialized left-value: assert \initialized(&j);
test.c:3:[kernel] warning: completely indeterminate value in j.
[...]
```

Is there a way to treat reading `j` as reading an unspecified value?
I would prefer to do this programmatically (inside Frama-C) without modifying the analyzed source code.

I'm running Frama-C Neon.

Answer (score 1):

Reading uninitialized (indeterminate) memory during the execution of a C program is undefined behavior [or might as well be treated as such](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined). A slicer for C programs does not need preserve executions that lead to undefined behavior. Thus, since all executions of your program lead to undefined behavior, virtually any slice produced by Frama-C's slicing plug-in is a correct slice. You could have obtained the same behavior if you had written `if (1 / 0) {`. For the reasons given in the blog post I linked to, there is not so much difference between the two.

---

As a solution, simply initialize `j` with the `Frama_C_interval()` built-in whose specification is provided in a file `__fc_builtin.h`:

```
#include <__fc_builtin.h>
...
int j = Frama_C_interval(0, 1);
```

---

If that's simpler for you, for a short example, you can set `j` to an unknown value as follows:

```
volatile int u;

int main() {
  int j = u;
  ...
```

**EDIT:**

Following a private discussion with Thomas, I added the following suggestion:

You could write a Frama-C plug-in that transforms a C program into an equivalent C program where every local variable is initialized. I would recommend that additional initializations are done with a statement:

```
Frama_C_make_unknown(&x, sizeof x);
```

Where `Frama_C_make_unknown` is a function of which you would have managed to have a prototype with specification included in the initial source code (so have to avoid the difficulty of adding it:)

```
extern int Frama_C_entropy_source;

/*@ requires \valid(p + (0 .. l-1));
    assigns p[0 .. l-1] \from Frama_C_entropy_source;
    assigns Frama_C_entropy_source \from Frama_C_entropy_source;
    ensures \initialized(p + (0 .. l-1));
*/
void Frama_C_make_unknown(char *p, size_t l);
```

After such a transformation, the slicing plug-in would work as you expect. If you encounter difficulties in making such a transformative plug-in, you can ask questions about that in frama-c-discuss or in StackOverflow (the latter is better, since Google does not index frama-c-discuss in any useful way).

Comment: Thanks, I've actually read the blog post you've referenced before. My trouble is that I need to slice the program rather with "executed on amd64" semantics than with C semantics. Is there a way to achieve the Frama_C_interval() behaviour programmatically for all variables without modifying the analyzed source code?

Comment: @thpani The examples of strange program behaviors in the blog post **are** executed on amd64. How does it make the world better if someone spends the time necessary to make a patch to change the behavior of local variables?

Comment: @thpani Wait a minute... Are you trying to slice testcases from a certain “software verification” competition that calls itself that despite containing a majority of reachability questions and, to add insult to injury, undefined behavior in the examples? Please contribute to fixing the testcases instead. I for one would not want to encourage further use of the `int j; if (j)` pattern, especially not in the “software verification” competition.